# Javascript / Jquery acces object with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic object property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name)

With an ajax call I receive an object: E

This objects holds a number of child elements: `width`, `height`, etc.

`console.log (E.width)` gives me all elements of `E.width`

When I assign a var: `tempElement = 'width'`

Why does console.log(e.tempElement) returns 'undefined' and how can i access a child element of the object by a variable

```
$(function () {
    $('#widthSelect').on('change', function () {
        var updateArray = new Array();
        updateArray[0] = 'height';
        updateArray[1] = 'rim';
        updateArray[2] = 'load';
        updateArray[3] = 'speed';
        updateArray[4] = 'brand';
        updateArray[5] = 'season';
        getValues(updateArray);
    });

    function getValues(updateArray) {
        var data = updateArray.join('=&') + '=';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '******',
            data: data,
            success: function (e) {
                element = updateArray[0];
                console.log(e.element);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
console.log( e[element] );
```

When you use "dot notation" like `e.element` then the bit after the `.` is taken literally as a property name. Your object doesn't have a property called `"element"` so you get `undefined`. If you use the array-style notation the bit inside the square brackets is evaluated as an expression and the result is used as the property name.

```
e.width
// is equivalent to
e["width"] // note the quotation marks
// and equivalent to
someVariable = "width";
e[someVariable]
// and also equivalent to
e[someFunction()]  // assuming someFunction() returns the string "width"
```